# PDFBox generated PDF dimensions (Height and Width) getting swapped

Tags: pdfbox

Let me give you an overview of my project first. I have a pdf which I need to convert into images(One image for one page) using PDFBox API and write all those images onto a new pdf using PDFBox API itself. Basically, converting a pdf into a pdf, which we refer to as PDF Transcoding.

Now, I have some cases wherein eveyrthing goes fine, i.e. the transcoded pdf exactly matches the original pdf contents, but just 1/10 cases are like, the dimensions of transcoded pdf is getting swapped somehow. For example, original pdf- 8.2 x 11.2
transcoded pdf- 11.2 x 8.2. In short, height is getting swapped with width. I don't know why this API is behaving differently for different files. If anyone could answer the same?

Thanks in advance, 
Vaibhav

Comment: A PDF page object can be rotated by a multiple of 90°. Maybe one of the used software packages respects this rotation while the other one doesn't.

Comment: Thanks mkl for getting back. But how do I recognize at the first place then, that what object will be rotated and what not, so that I can deliver the outputs equably in every condition?

Comment: As you are using PDFBox, you can query the rotation of a `PDPage page` using `page.findRotation()`. In essence it returns the value of the **Rotate** key of the page or (if not found there) its ancestors in the page tree.

Comment: Thanks mkl. I have already done that and it worked! Thanks again! :)

Comment: Ok. I'll make that an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Summarizing the results of the dialogue in the comments to the original question)*

Each page of a PDF has a rotation property which can indicate a rotation of the otherwise defined page coordinates, confer the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> **Rotate** integer *(Optional; inheritable)* The number of degrees by which the page shall be rotated clockwise when displayed or printed. The value shall be a multiple of 90. Default value: 0.
>
> *(Table 30* Entries in a page object *on page 78)*

E.g., a page by its media box being defined to have an A4 portrait format may still have to be displayed as an A4 landscape page.

In your case one of the used software packages seems to respect this rotation while the other one doesn't.

As you are using PDFBox, you can query the rotation of a `PDPage page` using

```
int rotation = page.findRotation();
```

In essence it returns the value of the **Rotate** key of the page or (if not found there) its ancestors in the page tree.

Comment: Thanks Mkl. Your suggestion worked out as expected. Now, we have set the rotation to 0 wherever we see that rotation is not 0.

Comment: I have one more doubt, if you can help:

For certain pdfs, which contain JBIG2 images, PDFbox implementation of convertToImage() method is failing silently without any exceptions or errors and finally, producing a PDF, but this time, just with blank content(white). I need to know how to resolve this issue? We have something like 
import org.apache.pdfbox.filter.JBIG2Filter;
which I don't know how to implement. I am searching on that, but to no avail. Could you please suggest?

Comment: I'm not really into the PDFBox page rendering base architecture. You had better make this a question in its own right. Quite recently at least one of the main PDFBox developers started answering some questions here on SO. Alternatively make it an issue in the Apache PDFBox JIRA system.